# Which is more efficient in java using jdbc, results.getString(1) or results.getString("field_name")

Tags: java, sql

Is there's a noteworthy difference? I'm talking about a program that spends a lot of its time reading results from queries, and some runs (these are web hits) are taking upwards of 2 minutes. If I can shave a few seconds off just by using integers instead of field names, I figure I get some time for free.

Comment: Have you tried? Have you *profiled* that it's really the `getString()` calls?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? (Although I don't think it will make any noticeable difference)

Comment: Well, the program I'm looking at isn't mine, and I don't have a dev environment set up to run it where I could profile it. It would take me days. Alternatively I could write a program to simulate the situation, but again that would take a little while, and I figured stackoverflow is filled with people who know things like this off the top of their head, so I thought I'd ask. The function in question does nothing but call .next() and get fields from the resultset, so it kinda has to be that.

Comment: ...or the database being slow I suppose.

Comment: If your data is taking minutes to come back, odds are it's not due to how the values are being pulled from the resultsets...

Comment: The `field_name` is preferred because the other option (called ordinal position) is dependent on the column order in the `SELECT` - change that order, and it's very likely to break your app.

Comment: if you use results.getString(“field_name”) the compiler will optimize it with results.getString(1). Decompile the class file and you will see

Comment: @anfy2002us How is that supposed to work if i use a value thats not known until runtime? Completely leaving aside the part that the compiler doesnt parse the SQL to do that mapping in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would depend on the implementation of the java.sql.ResultSet.  As an example, the DB2 implementation for zOS must hash the java.lang.String back into the columned index whereas the indexed version uses the index directly.  I'm guessing other implementations are similiar.  The additional processing time would be negligible.

Unless you are needing to stretch every bit of performance you can, I think the cost of using indexes versus the actual column name is not worth it.  There is a cost to maintainability.

Comment: We are using DB2 here at work and i did some performance testing. Measuring the total overhead of EJBs, 2 layers using Reflection + Converting and processing data the time spend getting the stuff from the database was more than 95% of the total time. Just to support the "The additional processing time would be negligible."

Answer (score 3):

**There is not a noteworthy difference in this case.**

If some queries are taking upwards of 2 minutes, I highly doubt this is from spending time comparing strings in this manner.  It's much more likely that the queries are slow.

You should run a profiler on your database to isolate the long running queries.  Then either re-index your database tables to better support those queries, or modify those queries to use the existing indices.